# Basic twitter client

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a basic twitter client which is able to read/update/send tweets and also searching through friends tweet and hash tagging. So far my app can login and send tweets to the wall. But i have no idea about the rest especially read and update tweets. Any information would be very helpful. Thank's a lot..

Comment: Maybe you can use twitter library? Such as twitter4j? They have special android build at their offsite.

Comment: Sending / Receiving Direct Messages
You can send and receive direct messages via Twitter.sendDirectMessage() / Twitter.getDirectMessages().

I found this. But still confused how to integrate those codes to my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding Twitter4J library to your build path.

To read tweets and send messges do like,
From your Auth Token and Key you retrieved make Twitter object,

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY);
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
cb.setOAuthAccessToken(token);
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(secret);
cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
```

Using this twitter object you can get Timelines,Mentions and send directMessages like..

```
twitter.getUserTimeline();
twitter.sendDirectMessage(screenName, text);
twitter.getMentions();
```

I suggest you to go to this links first,

1) Link for **[Twitter4J jar](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)** file

2) Link for **[Code Examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)** for Twitter4J

3) and **[JavaDoc](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html)** for Twitter4J Api

Comment: which function reguires to read tweets. Is there any way to read last tweet and view it in a textview. I tried                Twitter getter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();    DirectMessage message = getter.getDirectMessage(recipientId, message);                                                            tweetview.setText(message);   But it didn't work. How can i reach recipientId. I know i ask a lot. But i am new in android and this is my homework in my university

Comment: @eceçalıkuş 1)why dont you create twitter object as shown above in my answer?
2)can't get the last single tweet..but can get timeline list and from that list you can show list.get(0)th item as latest tweet
3)also see the code example link and you will get code demo for all your question
and and and..use them first as given and ask me if you find any difficulty.